# Force www to directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this application directory

http://www.example.com/application

When user browse without www, (e.g. example.com/application), i want to force and redirect them to http://www.example.com/application

How can i achieve using .htaccess.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect non www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect www to non www, the code is similar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/application$1 [R=301,L]
so for my case, it will be like this ? is there anyway not to put application directory name manually ?